# Extract number from Alphanumeric QString

Tags: c++, qt, integer, qt5, alphanumeric

I have a QString of **"s150 d300"**. How can I get the numbers from the QString and convert it into integer. Simply using 'toInt' is not working.

Let say, from the QString of **"s150 d300"**, only the **number after the alphabet 'd'** is meaningful to me. So how can I extract the value of **'300'** from the string?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to use regular expressions as shown below:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString str = "s150 dd300s150 d301d302s15";

    QRegExp rx("d(\\d+)");

    QList<int> list;
    int pos = 0;

    while ((pos = rx.indexIn(str, pos)) != -1) {
        list << rx.cap(1).toInt();
        pos += rx.matchedLength();
    }
    qDebug()<<list;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
(300, 301, 302)
```

Thanks to the comment of @IlBeldus, and according to the information QRegExp will be [deprecated](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#notes-for-qregexp-users), so I propose a solution using [`QRegularExpression`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html):

Another solution:

```
QString str = "s150 dd300s150 d301d302s15";

QRegularExpression rx("d(\\d+)");

QList<int> list;
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = rx.globalMatch(str);
while (i.hasNext()) {
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
    QString word = match.captured(1);
    list << word.toInt();
}

qDebug()<<list;
```

Output:

```
(300, 301, 302)
```

Comment: QRegExp is deprecated in Qt5, QRegularExpression should be used instead. Duplicate question from Qt Forums: https://forum.qt.io/topic/81717/extract-number-from-an-alphanumeric-qstring

Comment: Both versions are still supported, look at this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html.

Comment: Also it is not duplicate, I have responded 2 hours ago, instead the forum has been resolved 15 minutes ago.

Comment: I have tested my solution in Qt 5.9.1

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to say you copied the answer, on the contrary. It was more a note for OP.
On the QRegExp matter I stand by my statement. While both of them still work (mainly for compatibility reasons with other classes like QSortFilterProxyModel) QRegExp is deprecated: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#details states "Note: In Qt 5, the new QRegularExpression class provides a Perl compatible implementation of regular expressions and is recommended in place of QRegExp."

Comment: I have proposed another solution considering your comments. Thank you. :P

Comment: I appreciate your assist, sir. But can you explain what the coding means? RegEx is a bit confusing for newbies such as myself.

Can you include comments for each code line to explain what exactly does the line do?

`QRegularExpression rx("d(\\d+)");
QList<int> list;
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = rx.globalMatch(str);
while (i.hasNext()) {
QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
QString word = match.captured(1);
list << word.toInt();`

Comment: The following regular expression: `some_letter(\\d+)` indicates that the occurrence is looking for a sub-string containing `some_letter` followed by digits (`\d` means a single digit, but by saying`\d+`, you are asking for at least one digit), And in your case it happens. In your case `some_letter` is `d`

Answer (score 4):

Why all the trouble if you can just do:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>

const auto serialNumberStr = QStringLiteral("s150 d300");

int main()
{
    const QRegExp rx(QLatin1Literal("[^0-9]+"));
    const auto&& parts = serialNumberStr.split(rx, QString::SkipEmptyParts);

    qDebug() << "2nd nbr:" << parts[1];
}
```

Prints out: `2nd nbr: "300"`

Answer (score 2):

If your string is split into space separated tokens like the example you gave you can simply get the value out of it by splitting it, then finding a token that meets your needs and then taking the number part of it. I used atoi after converting the qstring into something I'm more comfortable with but I think there's a more efficient way.

Although this isn't as flexible as regular expressions, it should give better performance for the example you provided.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

int main() {
    QString str = "s150 d300";

    // foreach " " space separated token in the string
    for (QString token : str.split(" "))
        // starts with d and has number
        if (token[0] == 'd' && token.length() > 1)
            // print the number part of it
            qDebug() <<atoi(token.toStdString().c_str() + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already answers giving a suitable solution to this problem, but I think it might be also helpful to stress that `QString::toInt` won't work because the string being converted should be a textual representation of a number and in the given example it is an alpha-numeric expression in a non-standard notation, thus it is necessary to manually process it as already suggested in order to make it "understanable" for Qt to perform the convertion.